# How to dynamically render a control?

Tags: asp.net

How do I go about rendering an asp.net control on a web page from a string in code behind?

For example, say I have the aspx page below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="nrm.FRGPproposal.Questionnaire1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        //want to render a text box here
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What could I do in my Page_Load event to render a TextBox into the div?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what do i do here to render a TextBox in the div from the aspx page?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caution there may be compilation problems here.  But basically add a placeholder control to the code in front as such.
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="nrm.FRGPproposal.Questionnaire1" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:placeholder id="placeHolder" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create a TextBox in the code behind programmatically.  You will need to include System.Web.UI in order to get the textbox.
Then Add the control to the controls collection on the placeHolder. Set whatever properties  you like on the text box programmatically

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(tb); //tb is referring to the name that you want to name your element. in this example given was TextBox. so the name of text box is tb. 

}
```

Comment: As @Tehrab suggests below this is best done in an earlier life cycle moment like Page Init and not page load.

Comment: Do you know how I could create a new TextBox object like you are doing from a string like "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to be able to add a text box merged into the middle of some string within the div?  Like say you had the string "Enter Name [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox]" and you want the "[System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox]" to be rendered as a TextBox control?

Comment: Sort of.  I don't need the extra stuff in the string you mentioned ("Enter Name").  Basically I will be pulling the control type string from a database table that is filled through an admin section.  I might just use a switch/case statement since the number of controls available is relatively small but I was curious if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I see.  You should use .GetType() on the textbox to get the string.  Then you can use the typeof keyword (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) and get back a new instance of the textbox when pulling the string from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

Add two attributes to your div element : `<div runat="server" id="myDiv"></div>`

Then

```
   TextBox tb = new TextBox();
   this.myDiv.Controls.Add(tb);
```

If you want to render a Custom UserControl you can use the above code

```
  MyUserControl control  = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/My_VirtualPathToControl");
  this.myDiv.Controls.Add(control);
```

(You must register your control in the aspx file)

One more think.
Be cautious when you execute code on Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to rebuild the controls in the `Page_Init` method in order to read the controls' state/values on PostBack.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    placeHolder.Controls.Add();
}
```